# Uncaught TypeError: *** is not a function in a React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm passing an object as an argument in a React component's constructor. Then, I want to call one of the object's function, but get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.layout.getWbsLayout is not a function
    at new Wbs (Wbs.tsx:50)
    at react-dom.js:4749
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (react-dom.js:4529)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (react-dom.js:4748)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (react-dom.js:4734)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react-dom.js:4642)
    at Object.mountComponent (react-dom.js:11542)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (react-dom.js:4825)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react-dom.js:4712)
    at Object.mountComponent (react-dom.js:11542)
```

I read some posts about binding methods to this in the constructor, but as I am calling a function of an object I passed as an argument, I am not sure this applies here, and still got a similar message saying `bind is not a function`.

Here's my code, `Wbs` is the root React component, `WbsLayout` is an object I pass as a parameter to Wbs' constructor.

The error happens in the constructor, when I do `this.layout.getWbsLayout()`
Note that I tried to call the function in `ComponentDidMount` instead, but got the same error.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import WbsLayout from "../layout/WbsLayout";

interface WbsProps {}
interface WbsState {
    wbsElements: any[];
    wbsEdges: any[]
}

class Wbs extends React.Component<WbsProps, WbsState>{

    public cy: Cy.Instance;
    private layout: WbsLayout;
    private s: snap.Paper;
    private renderer: WbsRenderer;

    public state : WbsState;

    constructor(props: WbsProps, layout: WbsLayout) {
        super(props);
        this.layout = layout;
        this.cy = this.layout.cy;

        // this does show a json object in the console, hence layout can be accessed
        console.log(layout.cy.elements().jsons());

        this.layout.getWbsLayout(); //The error happens here

        // initial state
        this.state = {
            wbsElements: [],
            wbsEdges: [],
        };
    }

    public render() {

        const wbsElements: any = this.state.wbsElements.map((element: any) => (
            <WbsElement
                key={element.wbsElementBox.nodeId}
                wbsElementBox={...element.wbsElementBox}
                wbsElementTitle={...element.wbsElementTitle}
                wbsElementId={...element.wbsElementId}
            />
        ));

        const wbsEdges: any = this.state.wbsEdges.map((edge: any) => (
            <WbsEdge
                key={edge.edgeId}
                edgeId={edge.edgeId}
                sourceWbsElementData={...edge.sourceWbsElementData}
                targetWbsElementData={...edge.targetWbsElementData}
            />
        ));

        return (
            <svg>
                {wbsElements}
                {wbsEdges}
            </svg>
        );
    }
}

export default Wbs;
```

Here's `WbsLayout`:

export class WbsLayout  {

```
    public cy: Cy.Instance;

    constructor(graph: any, Options?: Options) {

        this.cy = cytoscape({
            headless: true,
            elements: graph
        });

    }

    public getWbsLayout(): any {
        const wbsElements: any = this.cy.collection("node[visibility = 'visible']").map((n: Cy.CollectionNodes) =>
            ({
                wbsElementBox: {
                    nodeId: n.data().id,
                    x: n.data().x,
                    y: n.data().y,
                    width: n.data().width,
                    height: n.data().height
                },
                wbsElementTitle: {
                    text: n.data().title
                },
                wbsElementId: {
                    text: n.data().wbsId
                }
            })
        );

        const wbsEdges: any = [
            {
                edgeId: '5',
                sourceWbsElementData: {
                    nodeId: '1',
                    x:464.359375,
                    y:30,
                    width:100,
                    height:40,
                    layoutStyle: 0
                },
                targetWbsElementData: {
                    nodeId:'1.5',
                    x:867.875,
                    y:100,
                    width:130.84375,
                    height:40,
                    layoutStyle: 1
                }

            }
        ];

        return {
            wbsElements,
            wbsEdges
        };
    }

    ....
}
export default WbsLayout;
```

Here's how I instantiate Wbs:

```
let graph: any = {
    nodes: [],
    edges: []
};

let layout: WbsLayout = new WbsLayout(graph);
let wbs = new Wbs(null, layout);
```

I can see json objects in Wbs' constructor:
    console.log(layout.cy.elements().jsons());

Comment: Think you should execute `wbsElements` and `wbsEdges` functions in your render

Comment: Probably because `React.createElement`, when instantiating your component, doesn't pass a `WbsLayout` instance to your constructor.

Comment: How are you passing the `layout` to the constructor? In react if you want to pass something you do it using the `props`.

Comment: I've just edited my post to answer your question. I do pass the layout to Wbs when I instantiate, and I can access it if I run a console.log(...) within Wbs' s constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Problem turned out to be unrelated, but it's worth remembering that React is very good at throwing early warnings about these kinds of things in that it will 'test' your components and throw errors or warnings if things don't 'look' right, e.g., if props aren't coming in as expected. The early warnings are sometimes *so* 'helpful' that they can throw off your normal debugging instincts.

---

Original answer:

Either shield the function call from executing before the props get passed in or set default props setting some kind of dummy or fallback function behavior.

In the constructor:

```
if (this.layout.getWbsLayout) {
  this.layout.getWbsLayout();
}
```

Other options:

- define a default value for the function.
- execute the function in `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`, depending on your needs. Lifecycle hooks are the right place to execute data instantiation. The constructor is best for state and static calls like binding your class's functions, as needed.

Comment: I tried to call within componentDidMount without success, same error: componentDidMount() {
        let layout: any = this.layout.getWbsLayout();
        this.setState(
            {
                wbsElements: layout.wbsElements,
                wbsEdges: layout.wbsEdges
            }

        );
    }

Comment: Did you try the `if` approach -- could even make the test more specific by looking at the `typeof`. I don't the approach long-term, but it would help you narrow down the root cause of the problem. It would also help if you pare down the code, at least here, to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. There's so much code here, but really only about 5-10 lines that seem relevant, but maybe there's more to it that I'm missing.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ben. Basically, despite me being able to console.log the layout, it wasn't passed, as Nitzan and Andrew mentioned above. I refactored a bit, and passed the layout through props instead, and it now works like a charm. Btw, following your advice, and executing my data instantiation in componentWillMount.

Comment: @GregForel Glad to hear it!  We've all been there before. You think a problem is related to the new thing you're doing... at least that's how it happens for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error tekst and it looks like this question pops up as number 1 question so I will just write my solution here.

I had this code:

```
 onClick={this.setSelected(item)}
```

and had to change it to this:

```
 onClick={() => this.setSelected(item)}
```